# Improving Quantum State Distinguishability through Embedding

Tags: quantum-operation, trace-distance, state-discrimination, trace-norm

Consider the following map, $\mathcal{E}:\mathcal{L}(H_A) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(H_{AB})$,
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho_A|U_{AB}, U_{AC}) = {\rm Tr_C} \left[ U_{AC}U_{AB}(\rho_A\otimes |0_B\rangle\langle 0_B|\otimes |0_C\rangle\langle 0_C|)U_{AB}^{\dagger}U_{AC}^{\dagger}\right]
$$
Here, $U_{AB}$ is a Unitary between systems $A$ and $B$, and, $U_{AC}$ is a Unitary between systems $A$ and $C$.
[image]
Show that, there exists unitary $U_{AB}^*$ such that, for *any* two states $\rho$, $\sigma$, and *any* unitary $U_{AC}$,
$$||\mathcal{E}(\rho|U_{AB}^*, U_{AC}) - \mathcal{E}(\sigma|U_{AB}^*, U_{AC})||_1 \geq ||\mathcal{E}(\rho|I_{AB}, U_{AC}) - \mathcal{E}(\sigma|I_{AB}, U_{AC})||_1 $$

Here, $I_{AB}$ is the Identity Map on $H_{AB}$, and, $||A||_1 = {\rm Tr}(|A|)$ is the Trace-Norm of $A$.

**Generalization**:
What conditions does $U_{AB}^*$ need to satisfy in general so that this inequality holds ?

**Note**: 
This result can be interpreted as, if the state of system $A$ is suitably embedded in a larger Hilbert-Space before evolving $A$ with a Completely Positive Trace-Preserving Map, then, the distinguishability of the state can be improved.